# Request to Google Analytics sent but event not recorded

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, event-tracking

I am trying to track outbound links with the following script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX']); //hidden number, well configured
    //works
    $("a[href$='pdf']").click(function(){ 
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'PDF', 'Download', $(this).attr('href') ]);
    });
    //doesn't works
    $("a.external_link").click(function(e){ 
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outbound', 'Click', $(this).attr('href')]);      
    });
});
```

The first function to track pdf links works well. The second one doesn't. 
I added a target=_blank on the links I want to track, so I think it is not a delay issue.
I have checked in Firebug and the GA request is well sent and all parameters seems to be good. 
I clicked on the links, I know that some people also did, and these events have not appeared in GA although it has been implemented for 4 days.

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your post that all the links to be tracked has a target="_blank" in the attributes.

Why not try something in the order of:

```
$("a[target$='_blank']").click(function(e){ 
    //gaq function here...      
});
```

Instead of referencing the href attribute, reference the target attribute rather.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But I don't want to track all links that have target="_blank". I don't think selector is the problem since the request is sent when clicking on the right links (with external_link class).